# Are Tony Stark and Pepper Potts back together?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war, spider-man-homecoming

Spoilers ahead, so do not read if you're not up to date with Marvel Movies.

and maybe this is a silly or unanswerable question but it bugged me after watching Spiderman homecoming.

During Civil War, I don't remember the exact quote but Tony said she'd left him and it sounded pretty final.

At the end of Spiderman Homecoming there was talk about a marriage proposal (somewhat jokingly as the real announcement didn't happen).   The obvious answer I suppose is that they got back together, though that as never explained and, frankly, seems like bad writing.   It was nice to see her make a cameo, but is there any official word on this?   Did they split and get back together?

Part of me thinks this is a really dumb question where that's the obvious answer, but I'm still a little bit curious if there's more info on this anywhere.

Comment: Thanks.  I searched, but didn't see that question.   It's exactly what I wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that Happy Hogan flipped Stark a ring just as he was walking into the press conference at the end of Spiderman: Homecoming, I'd say they're back together.  I also recall him saying to her that this would be a perfect time to announce their engagement, since they had a press conference scheduled and he pretty much knew (or hoped) that Peter Parker would reject his offer to join The Avengers.

Comment: I know all that.   My question was more along the lines of "this seemed strange", which might not fit within the proper line of questions.    I was wondering if Marvel offered any explanation, cause that was a pretty huge 180 degree turn that went unexplained.

Comment: There's a solid answer at the link provided as to why the people behind the movie wanted them to be separated, but it's reasonable to think that any couple can reconcile.  And not every action in the MCU is explained "in universe".  I'd like to know how Stark repeatedly gets punched in the nuts by his Iron Man suit in IM3 and isn't singing Soprano by the end of the movie.